# Обращению к масиву рандомных картинок

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, изображения, бот

Есть масив из картинок randoming. Как заставить бота обращаться к нему и брать оттуда картинку рандомно?

```
import amino
import random
import datetime
from gtts import gTTS
import requests
import os
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
from io import BytesIO
from getpass import getpass

def on_message(data):
    content = data.message.content
    chatId = data.message.chatId

    randomimg = ["amino.jpeg", "amino2.jpeg"] # рандом картинка

    if content.lower().startswith("nsercet"):
        with open("randomimg", "rb") as file:
            sub_client.send_message(chatId=chatId, file=file, fileType="image")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `random.choice`:

```
with open(random.choice(randomimg), "rb") as file:
```

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы обращение было к целой папке в которой много изображений и из этой папки брал рандомно?

Comment: Ну прочитайте список файлов из папки через os.listdir и выбирайте уже из него